# Groovy: How to manually create a date? - GroovyRuntimeException

Tags: groovy, runtimeexception

I want to export some data from a web api using Groovy. Therefore I want to manually set a date from which I want to begin. For example I want to start from 31th of december 2020.

Therefore I used this code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
LocalDateTime fromDate = new LocalDateTime(2020, 12, 31, 10, 00);
```

When executing the script I get a `GroovyRuntimeException`:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.time.LocalDateTime(Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` does not have a public constructor. Use one of the many factory `of()` methods:

```
LocalDateTime fromDate = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 31, 10, 0, 0)
//or
LocalDateTime fromDate = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 31), 
                                          LocalTime.of(10, 0, 0))
//etc.
```

Comment: I got: `unable to resolve class LocalDateTime.of`

Comment: Don't use `new`.